# socket.io server object options, what are the implications between the two?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

From the socket.io documentation [here](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#new-Server-httpServer-options), you can use the `http.Server` object, or simply pass a port number into the socket.io server object.  ***What is the difference?***

### Create the socket.io Object

```
const io = require('socket.io')({
  path: '/test',
  serveClient: false,
});
```

### Either create a server object from the http library and inject it into the socket.io object

```
const server = require('http').createServer();

io.attach(server, {
  pingInterval: 10000,
  pingTimeout: 5000,
  cookie: false
});

server.listen(3000);
```

### Or simply pass a port number to the socket.io object and it will make a server for you

```
io.attach(3000, {
  pingInterval: 10000,
  pingTimeout: 5000,
  cookie: false
});
```

Comment: By using the port, you create a server seperately for socket. For http connections, you have to create another server. By attaching to an existing http server, you run a single server for your apis and socket.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't realize that.  And since I only need the WebSocket functionality, no HTTP for me!. If you sum that up I will give you credit for an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By attaching to a server, you can use socket.io functions on an existing server application, that already serves files and responds to api calls. By passing a port as param, socket.io will spawn a separate server for its functions. If you are using this only for socket functionality, either is fine.

But, attaching to a server is preferable when you want to use SSL. In that case, you can simply pass a HTTPS Server. I could not find any example with port option to use SSL.